# How to pass arguments to a function automatically?

Tags: vb.net

I want to pass txt1 and txt2 through this function to validate both userinput boxes however i can only pass one argument at a time which means ill have to make 2 functions? is there a way where txt2 can pass automatically after txt1 in all the places txt1 was entered.

```
Private Function isNumericOnly(ByVal txt1 As String, ByVal txt2 As String) As Boolean

    Dim iLen As Integer
    Dim iCtr As Integer
    Dim sChar As String

    iLen = Len(txt1)
    If iLen > 0 Then
        For iCtr = 1 To iLen
            sChar = Mid(txt1, iCtr, 1)
            If Not sChar Like "[0-9]" Then Return False

        Next

        Return True

    End If


End Function
```

Comment: It is possible to specify default text in the method signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  one validation method:

```
Public Function DigitsOnly(text As String) As Boolean
    Return text IsNot Nothing AndAlso text.All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit)
End Function
```

Then you pass the text of both `TextBoxes` to it:

```
Dim isValid As Boolean = DigitsOnly(txt1.Text) AndAlso DigitsOnly(txt2.Text)
```

Note that  the method returns `True` if you pass an empty string. If you don't want that  use:

```
Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) AndAlso text.All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit)
```

If you have many controls (or strings) that you want to validate you could use a collection:

```
Dim allTextBoxes As TextBox() = {txt1, txt2, txt3}
Dim isValid = allTextBoxes.All(Function(txt) DigitsOnly(txt.Text))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I've used your method, however i still get an error. This is my code at the moment.  ` Public Function DigitsOnly(ByVal txt1 As String, ByVal txt2 As String) As Boolean
        Return txt1 IsNot Nothing AndAlso txt1.All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit)
    End Function'

Comment: I guess that you haven't imported `System.Linq`, have you?

Comment: @Ali: note that currently the method returns `True` if you pass an empty string `""`. If you don't want that you have to use `Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) AndAlso text.All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit)`. I've edited  my answer accordingly.